# Automatic privileged column level encryption

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to design a table in Postgres that has a column whose value is always stored encrypted (without having to encrypt it manually at insert or update) and is always decrypted if the user has enough privileges to view the data? I am actually talking about a database feature and I am not interested in creating that manually.

For example, consider the following pseudocode:

```
CREATE TABLE xyz (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    info TEXT NOT NULL ENCRYPTED FOR ROLE 'admin' 
)
```

Then if I ran:

```
INSERT INTO xyz(info) VALUES("hello world")
```

It would result in

```
id | info
---------
 1 | #@$##$DFS
```

And if I am admin and I queried the data it would automatically show me the decrypted value while any other user would see the value as encrypted.

Does such feature exist in Postgres?

Comment: Just don't give the `SELECT` permission on the column to the non-privileged users, so they can't see the content at all? Why would they need to be able to access an encrypted value?